# decent_exposure creates double entries each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'am using `decent_exposure` gem and `cocoon` gem for nested forms and after each create or update I am getting duplicate entries. What am I doing wrong? X_X

**Controller**

```
class Admin::DealsController < ApplicationController
  expose :deals
  expose :deal, attributes: :deal_params

  def create
    if deal.save
      redirect_to [:admin, deal], notice: 'Deal was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if deal.update(deal_params)
      redirect_to [:admin, deal], notice: 'Deal was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def deal_params
    params.require(:deal).permit :title, :end_date,
                                 deal_variants_attributes: [:id, :title, :description, :price, :discount, :_destroy]
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_variants

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deal_variants, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem today and here is my solution and explanation:

This happens because `decent_exposure` already sets required attributes for you, and when you call `.update(deal_params)` it duplicates entries since first instance of `DealVariant` was [set by decent_exposure](https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure/blob/d7736dfe7bfc135c23d3e9844986339bd2df1505/lib/decent_exposure/strategies/assign_from_method.rb#L15), and second one was [set by `.update(deal_params)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) call. What you need to do instead is to use simple `.save` method in both `create` and `update` actions.